# How to manage CodeIgniter project code in a big project

Tags: php, codeigniter, project, project-management

I have some personal doubts regarding CodeIgniter project management.
I am having more than 1 year experience in CodeIgniter as a developer.
But now I am working on a project (e-commerce) which is totally managed under me and I am a single developer.
Few things at which I am confused at is ...

- Confusion about either create library or model !?
- when passing variables to model/library, either send via function parameter or setting as class object variable of that model/library !?

Comment: I ended up using libraries for shared logic (anything that need to be in several places), models for data access only and controller for any single use logic (only needed to use in that controller). However since I stopped using CI I have changed the way I work to fit around new structures. I would recommend looking at laravel4, because CI is slowly falling behind the times.

Answer (score 1):

so with the usual disclaimers -- my suggestion is to use Libraries for interacting with 3rd parties -- the credit card transaction, creating shipping, etc. Besides separation another reason is that often these services will have PHP libraries that you want to integrate.

otherwise use models. start out general and then refactor so that the models are very specific. use folders to help organize. try and clearly separate out responsibilities. separate display versus the e-commerce tasks. the model that displays the product should be separate from the model that populates the cart. for example:

models/store/product  -- display product and its variations

models/cart/item -- gets the current price, validates inventory etc

for many reasons i think its cleaner to do form validation in a model. form fields are available in the model.  then the controller is just asking - did this form validate or not. Put validation on any/every form or post call even if there is no obvious user input.

more suggestions: do not use the CI cart library. your admin controllers (create a product , review an order, etc) should be in a completely separate application folder. models/cart/item gets the price directly from product table - do not pass the price in the buy button. keep in mind that people can put things in a cart and come back a week later - having price and inventory checks should be part of the checkout process.

its not a real "order" until you get the money. so however you do the checkout process - have a table that is just the completed final orders.

Comment: "the model that displays the product should be separate from the model that populates the cart"....
I like this idea. And most probably I follow this way.
But when I need to do same kind of thing in both the tasks.
Should I write in both models or should I call from from one model to another?

Comment: it depends but i think in general its always better to separate models especially making it easier to find things six months later. also on what i'm working on there is not a single product on a product page - there is a product that has variations in sizes, colors, etc - each variation has its own SKU and inventory amount.  so my product display is getting a group of related products. versus the product for the cart is checking one SKU - its price, inventory, etc.

Comment: I understand the point of separating the functions individually. and that is how HMVC works...Cool.
But wait a sec...for ex. I need to fetch product price in main page and also in product detail page. So should I add code in both the models (mdl_home & mdl_product) ? or Should I add in one model and call that one from all other models?
If I write one function in individual all models. One change leads to change in all models....!!!! :Confused:

Comment: so thats why i said "it depends". again for what i'm doing -- and for many real world e-commerce implementations -- the "product" page has variations that have different SKUs and different prices. even a single book can have paperback and hardcover. so its an object or array with different prices. VERSUS putting a single item in the cart, and then price checking it through checkout. otherwise if you really have single items per page with no variations - then it might make more sense. and you can always refactor later :-)